# ng serve not working after fixing vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

can someone please help me figure out why i cant start project after fixing 3 high vulnerabilities ? I did `npm audit` to see the vulnerabilities and then `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@15.2.1` to fix them.
Now when i do `ng serve` nothing happens so i tried `npm start` instead and  i get these errors:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! abc@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the abc@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-07T17_32_14_773Z-debug.log
```

this is in the the log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle abc@0.0.0~prestart: abc@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: abc@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\projects\abc\abc-vpn-o\management-ui\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\user\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\user\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Ruby31-x64\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\projects\abc\abc-vpn-o\management-ui
10 silly lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 3  signal: null
12 info lifecycle abc@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: abc@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid abc@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\projects\abc\abc-vpn-o\management-ui
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.20.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.17
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
22 error abc@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 3
23 error Failed at the abc@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

this is how package.json looks

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "subsink": "^1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "10.0.0-beta.32",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.155",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "22.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "22.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "ini": "1.3.6",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

i tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then `npm install` but same issue

Comment: You shouldn't _expect_ everything to work fine when CLI is on v15 and every other Angular dependency is on (now very old) v9. See e.g. https://update.angular.io for how to upgrade - by the looks of it you should be doing that _much_ more often.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages you installed are not readable.
Angular must follow all the packages of that version
The packages you have installed interfere with each other and do not follow a version

You can use this [link](https://update.angular.io/) to solve the problem
Match your copies first and then click the **npm start** or **ng serve** command

**Note that it is best to do Angular's offer and update your project packages a copy, a copy**